# Joint Pdf of Triangular and Uniform Random Variable

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

The number of balls Ali takes to the cricket club is a triangular PDF. If X is a random variable denoting the number of balls taken to the club then the `PDF` is given by the following formula. 
$$f_X(x) = \frac{2x}{16} , 0<x<4$$ 
and the number of balls Ali takes back home is a uniform random variable between 0 and twice the number of balls he takes to the club. I have been able to identify the second uniform `PDF` as
$$f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{8}, 0<y<8$$
But I am unable to find the joint `PDF` of these two functions i.e $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = ?$$
Can anybody please help me in finding the way how to approach this problem?

Comment: OP wrote:  `The number of balls Ali takes to the cricket club is a rectangular PDF. If X is a random variable denoting the number of balls taken to the club ` ......... Your pdf  $f(x) = \frac{2x}{16} , 0<x<4$ is not rectangular - it is triangular.

Comment: ah sorry! Just corrected the mistake. It is indeed a triangular PDF

Comment: The number of balls one carries should be a _discrete_ variable ... whereas your model descriptions are _continuous_. Can he really carry .18 of a ball? Makes no sense to me.

Comment: @wolfies: I was wondering that - see my answer.  But you only get a total probability of $1$ if you treat $f_X(x)$ as a density

Comment: Indeed, the given function is not a valid probability mass function.

Comment: @wolfies Well the given problem draws it as a continuous line so I have to assume it as continuous. But I agree it does not make sense to carry 0.18 balls to the club or back home

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ali seems to be able to carry fractional balls.

Your second density looks wrong: you have a conditional density   $$ f_{Y\mid X=x}(y) = \frac{1}{2x}, \quad 0<y<2x$$ and so the joint density is $$f_{X,Y}(x,y) =f_{Y\mid X=x}(y)\,f_{X}(x)  = \frac{1}{16}, \quad 0\lt y\lt 2x\lt 8$$ and I suspect this makes the marginal density $$ f_{Y}(y) = \frac{1}{4}- \frac{y}{32}, \quad 0<y<8$$ which is also a triangular distribution

Comment: Can you please explain why $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{4}-\frac{y}{32}$? Don't we just have to integrate $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ over x to get the marginal density of $f_Y(y)$ and does the integration not give us just $\frac{1}{4}$ when we integrate it over x and put limits 0 to 4?

Comment: You cannot have $x \lt \frac{y}2$ so $\displaystyle f_Y(y)=\int_{x=y/2}^4 \dfrac{1}{16}\, dx =\dfrac14-\dfrac{y}{32}$

Comment: Thanks @Henry. it helped a lot :) what will be the sample space of our joint pdf then?

Comment: $0\lt y\lt 2x\lt 8$ perhaps with equality too: a triangle